# C#, mouseClickEvent doesn't respond to right mouse click

Tags: c#, winforms, right-click, mouseclick-event

on click event doesn't respond to right mouse click. The event is for a richTextBox.
when I try the same code on the form it works fine.

what could be the problem?

EDIT: I use winforms

Comment: Do you mean RichTextBox and also is this WPF or ASP.NET or Winforms

Comment: Please show your code.
edit: If you are using javascript (for instance) it's a complete different problem then if you are using winform.

Comment: I use winforms. Their is no point in my code cause it's simple code that includes the event function and messagebox that should popup on the right click event.

Comment: Even though your problem is resolved, it would be nice if you could post a small code sample for the benefit of the community - so when someone else has the same problem there is already an available solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to check it on the MouseDown event.

```
private void TextBox_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        wasRightButtonClicked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The Click and MouseClick events are only generated by a left-click.  If you want to detect right-clicks then you have to implement the MouseDown or MouseUp event.

Comment: nvm I took the onmousedown event